# Django: How to pass variables from view to a template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm having trouble passing a variable from view to an html file. This is what I did so far:

My root directory (where the manage.py file is) contains the following folders:

- myapp
- myproject
- templates

myproject/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

myproject/settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

templates/index.html:

```
<p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
```

When running the server locally, the only thing it shows is "Hello" without the name. What's wrong?

Comment: Share your view.index code

Comment: Share your `views.py` file as well please or just the view that is rendering the variable `name`...

Answer (score 0):

So let's start with views.py. When your urls.py calls your function in views.py, it's asking it to render a template.

Let's walk through a view function:

`def index(request):` the function the view

`context = {'name':'Sol'}` the key in the dictionary is what the HTML can call it and the value is what HTML gets back. So, when you do "{{ name }}" in HTML, it is replaced by Django with "Sol".

`return render(request, "index.html", context)` Making Django render it, request is the parameter from the function, "index.html" is the html file that Django is going to render, and context is the key + value pair that Django is going to use to replace.